# Compiling Sundance-4.73

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, sundance

I am compiling Sundance-4.37 using gcc 3.4.6. SUNDANCE (Sentence UNDerstanding ANd Concept Extraction) and autoannotate are software developed by the NLP laboratory at the University of Utah. Sundance comes prepackaged with [OpinionFinder](http://www.cs.pitt.edu/mpqa/opinionfinderrelease/).

It is compiled using an install script. During compilation, throws the following error:

```
creating ../src/Makefile
g++ -Wall -Wno-deprecated -pipe -g -static -I../include -DHOME=\"/home/shahw/opinionfinder/software/sundance-4.37/\" -c -fPIC -o shared/activation.o activation.C
constituent.h:131: error: extra qualification ‘Constituent::’ on member ‘getWordhelper’
make: *** [shared/activation.o] Error 1
```

Lines 130-132 of constituent.h are:

```
protected:
  Word* Constituent::getWordhelper(unsigned int&, unsigned int) const;
};
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anyone reading this; there are a few more tweaks needed on the code. There is a tutorial here: http://www.christopia.net/2011/10/21/installing-and-running-opinion-finder-for-sentiment-analysis (note, it will only compile on 32 bit systems).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't use the class name as a prefix for the member functions inside the class, just if defining them outside. Just remove that prefix.

```
protected:
    Word* getWordhelper(unsigned int&, unsigned int) const;
};
```